# How do i remove Glary Utilities and Registry repair?

Tags: safely-remove-hardware

I'm trying to free up some disk space. How do i remove Glary Utilities and Registry repair?

Do i simply remove it the normal way via control panel/uninstall ?

Just want to make sure there's no special uninstaller ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just uninstall it.  But you are not going to gain very much hdd from a small utility like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find and run `unins000.exe` or `uninstall.exe` in its installation folder (`C:\Program Files\Glary Utilities\`).

Follow uninstall dialog and click *Yes* to uninstall it.

You can also do this in  `Add/Remove Programs`.

[image]
<sub>Taken from *uninstall-guides.specialuninstaller*</sub>